# No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, heroku, procfile

I get this error when trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails app. Here is the error in my command line:

```
 ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 29.5MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v21
remote:        https://agile-sea-1900.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/agile-sea-1900.git
   e5d3ad8..975d5eb  master -> master
```

I tried following the advice in "[No Procfile detected, using the default web server](http://blog.taylorrf.com/blog/2014/12/15/heroku-default-server/)" [[archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122100122/http://blog.taylorrf.com/blog/2014/12/15/heroku-default-server/)] - bundling the `thin` gem and creating a Procfile containing:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

But that didn't help.

Comment: I don't see any errors, just warnings. What does `heroku logs` show? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval

Comment: What is the contents of your `Procfile`?

Comment: Make sure P is capital in Procfile

Comment: My Procfile contains - 'web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT'

Comment: So if you use `Thin`, you need to replace `rails server` by `thin` in your `Procfile`

Comment: I am also getting this error -  Could not detect rake tasks
remote:        ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
remote:        and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri

Comment: What happens when you try to run bundle exec rake -P on your local? You may have an error in your rake file. You also might try `rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 6):

In top of information given in comments, you have this error because in your `Procfile`, you have:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

So the default `webrick` will be used.

In order to remove this warning, you should use an another web server like Unicorn, Thin or Puma.

Heroku now advocates to use Puma ( see [Changelog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/594) ).

And to getting started with Puma and Heroku, you can follow article [Deploying Rails Applications with the Puma Web Server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) on Heroku website.

Comment: What's the error in the Procfile there, aside from the fact it defaults to Webrick?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I ignored Procfile in .gitignore, due to the other online guide pages. At that time, they gave a instruction to hide files which declares environment variables containing mailer account info.
So, check your .gitignore file and remove if you see Procfile in it.